# does the current's direction on a loop with a magnetic field affect the torque?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, torque, magnetic-moment

I have a question in my book

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P5R55sR.png]

The question is very easy, but then my solutions manual gave me unexpected answers

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tSMmJEY.png]

I don't get how in d) they conclude the vectors go in the opposite direction, but in b) they go in the same direction. The only thing I could guess is that there's some assumed current direction but I can't find anything in my book about that. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right hand rule along the currents direction gives the area vectors direction after a little more research sorry for wasting space